# jQuery Accordion tab doesn't close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Can someone explain why my jQuery Accordion isn't closing?

See the tab that is `open` on page load. When I try to close, it keeps re-opening. Help?!

http://jsfiddle.net/02vz11f0/

Here's my **jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
        $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function () {
            var status = $(this).is(':hidden') ? 'open' : 'close';
            $(this).prev('h4').find('.accordion-status').html(status);
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
/* Separate component file for Accordion? */

/* line 72, sass/_layout.scss */
 #accordion {
    width: 100%;
}
/* line 73, sass/_layout.scss */
 .accordion-content {
    display: none;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 50px;
}
/* line 80, sass/_layout.scss */
 .accordion-content.default {
    display: block !important;
}
/* line 82, sass/_layout.scss */
 .accordion-status {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    right: 30px;
}
/* line 88, sass/_layout.scss */
 .accordion-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    padding: 35px 60px 35px 0;
    margin: 0;
}
/* line 94, sass/_layout.scss */
 .accordion-toggle span {
    margin-left: 60px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: It's your .accordian-content.default CSS rule, it's killing you. The click, toggles it shut, but then the CSS overrules what jQuery did,  causing it to be displayed again. So just remove the !important, and you should be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `default` class from the element within the `.slideToggle()` callback.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/auhww9x2/)

```
$('#accordion').find('.accordion-toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast', function () {
        var status = $(this).is(':hidden') ? 'open' : 'close';
        $(this).removeClass('default').prev('h4').find('.accordion-status').html(status);
    });
});
```

In your CSS, you had the following:

```
.accordion-content.default {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Which was preventing the content from being toggled.

You could also just remove `!important`, and it will work as expected too. You should avoid using it as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `!important` from:

```
.accordion-content.default {
  display: block !important;
}
```

It is overriding the action of the accordion.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/02vz11f0/1/

Answer (score 0):

As I put in the comment, it is the `!important` rule on your CSS selector `.accordion-content.default`. It overrides jQuery hiding the div. See this [link](http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/) as to how !important always overrides that property.